# Website Redirect on Server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver

I have a Linux server that runs my website, the URL looks like this:

```
mysite.com/SymbolicLink/
```

I had to create a SymbolicLink because of the file structure that looks like this:

```
/var/www/html/MyWebsite/Code/web/
```

So the SymbolicLink points to the web folder inside my folder structure. That is where my `index.php` file is.

How can I avoid all this SymLink business and just type `mysite.com` without having it display my file structure on the browser?

---

Using *Apache 2.4.7*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache for the web server software, you can use `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyWebsite/Code/web` in a VirtualHosts section of the the Apache configuration file, `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, to point to that folder as the root of your website.

E.g., you could include something like the following at the bottom of `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyWebsite/Code/web
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/MyWebsite/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/MyWebsite/logs/transfer.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are unfamiliar with the VirtualHost section, you can have multiple websites on one web server using VirtualHost sections in the `httpd.conf` file. The `DocumentRoot` directive specifies the directory to be used for the top-level, i.e., "root", for the website for mysite.com. You can also specify where individual error and transfer logs for this particular website should be located (create the "logs" directory first, if it doesn't exist). And you can specify a contact email address, which can be anything you like, for `ServerAdmin`. Using `ServerAlias www.mysite.com` allows either mysite.com or www.mysite.com to work, provided you have DNS configured to point www.mysite.com as well as mysite.com to the IP address of your server. After making changes to the `httpd.conf` file, restart Apache.

Additional information on using virutal hosts with Apache can be found at 
[Apache Virtual Host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Comment: Yes, I am using *Apache*. Could you explain how I would do this in a bit more detail? My Apache version is 2.4.7.

Comment: @J_Strauton, I added some additional details.